# Adding elements to tableview in JavaFX doesn't work

Tags: javafx, tableview

I want to add elements from a JSON Rest Webservice to a TableView in JavaFX. Altough the `ArrayList contains the right elements`, the TableView just shows the Column Names but no rows.

Here is my code:

```
private Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    private Gson g = new Gson();
    private ArrayList<Schueler> schueler = new ArrayList<Schueler>();
    private ArrayList<Lehrer> lehrer = new ArrayList<Lehrer>();
    private final String REST_SERVICE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/A07_Webservice/rest/ManagementService";

    @FXML
    private TableView<Schueler> tblSchueler;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Schueler, String> lastnameCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Schueler, String> idCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Schueler, String> firstnameCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Schueler, String> birthdateCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Schueler, String> svnrCol;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Lehrer> tblLehrer;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Lehrer, String> svnrLehrerCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Lehrer, String> firstnameLehrerCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Lehrer, String> lastnameLehrerCol;
    @FXML
    private Button btnGetSchueler;
    @FXML
    private Button btnGetLehrer;

    @FXML
    public void btnGetSchueler() {
        tblSchueler.getItems().removeAll(tblSchueler.getItems());

        setCellConfigurationsSchueler();

        Type t = new TypeToken<List<Schueler>>() {}.getType();
        String s = client.target(REST_SERVICE_URL).path("schueler").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
        List<Schueler> sch = g.fromJson(s, t);
        schueler = (ArrayList<Schueler>) sch;

        for(int i = 0; i < schueler.size(); i++) {
            tblSchueler.getItems().add(schueler.get(i));
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void btnGetLehrer() {
        tblLehrer.getItems().removeAll(tblLehrer.getItems());

        setCellConfigurationsLehrer();

        Type t = new TypeToken<List<Lehrer>>() {}.getType();
        String s = client.target(REST_SERVICE_URL).path("lehrer").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
        List<Lehrer> l = g.fromJson(s, t);
        lehrer = (ArrayList<Lehrer>) l;

        for(int i = 0; i < lehrer.size(); i++) {
            tblLehrer.getItems().add(lehrer.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Do you know why the TableView is empty? I printed the size of the arraylist and so I know that it contains the data.

Comment: Can you post the other relevant code, e.g the `Lehrer` class and the cell value factories you set on the columns?

Comment: Make your code a bit easier by replacing the `removeAll`  and `add` with a `setAll` passing your list of teachers.

Answer (score 0):

Create array of columns and add them to `@FXML private TableView<ObservableList<String>> tblSchueler;`

```
//Clear
tblSchueler_data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
tblSchueler.getItems().clear();
tblSchueler.getColumns().clear();

//Add columns
TableColumn tc[] = {
        new TableColumn("Key"),
        new TableColumn("Value")
};

for(int i=0; i<tc.length; i++) {
    final int j = i;
    tc[i].setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
            return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
        }
    });
    Platform.runLater(() -> tblSchueler.getColumns().add(tc[j]));
}

//Add rows
ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
Iterator entries = map.entrySet().iterator();
while(entries.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String,String> s = (Map.Entry<String, String>) entries.next();
    row.add(s.getKey());
    row.add(s.getValue());
    tblSchueler_data.add(row);
}
Platform.runLater(() -> tblSchueler.setItems(tblSchueler_data));
```